# find all outbound flights from specified airport on specified day and time

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I need to find all outbound flights to all destinations from a specific airport and after a given time of the day. Is there a website that allows searching outbound flights with these specifications?

In my case, I need all flights from Stansted airport (London) on January 30 after 8 PM, no matter the destination. stanstedairport.com and skyscanner.co.uk don't offer this service.

I appreciate your tips.

Comment: Most airports let you see all departures for a given day. Schedules generally don't vary that much day-to-day except for seasonal routes, so that would give you an idea of what it will be. It will also show you what airlines fly into that airport, so you can query the individual airlines as well.

Comment: What on earth would you need that selection of information for?

Comment: @HenningMakholm You'd like to take a weekend break, you know your departure constraints are tight and you want to know your destination options?

Comment: @Calchas: Then what one wants is not a list of "which flights depart from the airport", but "which tickets are available to buy for me now".

Comment: It sounds more like a less-than-savory case of "someone told me they're going to the airport at that time, and I want to stalk where they might be going without actually asking them".

Answer (score 2):

ExpertFlyer can inspect flight timetables, and it has an option to search by departure airport; but it isn't a free service. It also doesn't tell you whether there are seats for sale on these flights, only that these are public commercial flights presently filed in the schedule.

```
Flight         Stops   Depart            Arrive            Aircraft     Duration         Frequency        Effective        Ending
U2 267         0       STN 20:00         BFS 21:15         319          1 hr 15 mins     T,W              15/01/19         27/03/19

EW 357         0       STN 20:00         CGN 22:15         319          1 hr 15 mins     T,W,F            11/01/19         30/01/19

FR 58          0       STN 20:00         NYO 23:15         73H          2 hrs 15 mins    W,F,Su           31/12/18         31/03/19

FR 4198        0       STN 20:05         BGY 23:00         73H          1 hr 55 mins     Daily            31/12/18         31/03/19

FR 9814        0       STN 20:05         BCN 23:20         73H          2 hrs 15 mins    M,T,W,Th,F,Su    31/12/18         31/03/19

FR 5998        0       STN 20:05         MAD 23:35         73H          2 hrs 30 mins    Daily            31/12/18         31/03/19

EK 34          0       STN 20:15         DXB 7:10 +1       77W          6 hrs 55 mins    Daily            31/12/18         30/03/19

FR 905         0       STN 20:20         ORK 21:45         73H          1 hr 25 mins     M,T,W,Th,F,Su    31/12/18         31/03/19

FR 8407        0       STN 20:30         WRO 23:30         73H          2 hrs 0 mins     M,W,Th,Su        31/12/18         31/03/19

FR 1194        0       STN 20:35         BLQ 23:40         73H          2 hrs 5 mins     M,T,W,Th,F,Su    31/12/18         31/03/19

U2 217         0       STN 20:45         GLA 22:00         319          1 hr 15 mins     T,W              31/12/18         27/03/19

FR 1166        0       STN 20:45         BFS 22:15         73H          1 hr 30 mins     T,W,Th,F,Sa,Su   31/12/18         31/03/19

FR 8887        0       STN 21:00         EDI 22:20         73H          1 hr 20 mins     T,W              31/12/18         27/03/19

FR 8347        0       STN 21:00         OPO 23:20         73H          2 hrs 20 mins    T,W,Th,F,Su      31/12/18         31/03/19

FR 271         0       STN 22:05         DUB 23:30         73H          1 hr 25 mins     Daily            31/12/18         14/03/19

PC 1164        0       STN 23:40         SAW 6:30 +1       320          3 hrs 50 mins    M,T,W,Th,F,Sa    22/01/19         31/01/19
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you add a link? I found their website but it requires subscription and I'm not sure how to get to the time table you found.

Comment: @NBK I have a subscription.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can search this directly but you can use 3rd party site like https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/departures/STN/?year=2019&month=1&date=8&hour=18 or Stansted's own departure page. You can't see Jan 30 (yet), but any Wed in January should look very similar.

Comment: Thanks for this. I couldn't find the info in the stansted airport web page, and the link provided didn't work. I need to find all outbound flights within a very specific time range.